# Updating junction table using laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Problem is simple I have a form that inserts data into Handymen table (everything except check boxes) and to Skill table (check boxes) however these are connected using junction table and when I click submit button, data is added to both tables however how do I make it update a junction table to add a new row, with skill_id and handyman_id just added?

```
function addhandyman()
{
    return view('layouts/addhandyman');
}
function pushdetails(Request $request)
{
$handyman = new Handyman();
    $handyman->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $handyman->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $handyman->street = $request->street;
    $handyman->postcode = $request->postcode;
    $handyman->town = $request->town;
    $handyman->save();
    $skill = new Skill();
    $skill->skill = $request->skill;
    $skill->save();
    return redirect('addhandyman');
}
```

---

```
@section('content')
 <h1>Add new Handyman</h1>
    <form action="{{url('pushdetails')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input type='text'  name='first_name' placeholder='Enter First Name' />
            <input type='text'  name='last_name'  placeholder='Enter Last Name'  />
            <input type='text'  name='street'  placeholder='Enter your Street' />
            <input type='text' name='postcode' placeholder='Enter your postcode' />
            <input type='text' name='town' placeholder='Enter your town' />
            <label>Carpenter</label>
            <input type='checkbox' name='skill' value='Carpenter' />
            <label>Plumber</label>
            <input type='checkbox' name='skill' value='Plumber' />
            <label>Painter</label>
            <input type='checkbox' name='skill' value='Painter' />
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Add new Handyman">
    </form>
@endsection
```

If any other files/code is required please let me know. Need help badly! Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a many-to-many relationship here? You don't want to end up with multiple `Carpenter` skills? You just want to link a handyman to the Skill `Carpenter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing about Laravel Models (Eloquent), when you create a new resource/model, it actually pulls the newly created Primary Key ID from your new resource in your database, into your model.

So when you do:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->field = "value";
$model->save();
// This will actually already have the Primary Key ID in it.
$mID = $model->id;
```

So the manual way would be to extract the separate ID's from the Models, and then add them into your table manually. Or you could setup relationships in your models using [Eloquent's Relationships Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).

So it would look something like this:

```
$h_id = $handyman->id;
$s_id = $skill->id;
DB::table('myJunctionTable')->insert(array('h_id' => $h_id, 's_id' => $s_id));
```

**With your code added:**

```
$handyman->first_name = $request->first_name;
$handyman->last_name = $request->last_name;
$handyman->street = $request->street;
$handyman->postcode = $request->postcode;
$handyman->town = $request->town;
$handyman->save();

$skill = new Skill();
$skill->skill = $request->skill;
$skill->save();

$h_id = $handyman->id;
$s_id = $skill->id;
DB::table('myJunctionTable')->insert(array('h_id' => $h_id, 's_id' => $s_id));

return redirect('addhandyman');
```